# PHP MySQL Insert from t1 to t3 where id from t1 and t2 are equal not working

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I´m trying to copy some content from table 1 to table 3 but only where id from table 1 and table 2 have same ID, but it's not working. It gives no error but it copies nothing.

Here's what I have right now.

```
include("conect.php");
$copiar = "INSERT INTO 
              temp_usr 
           SELECT 
               * 
           FROM 
               temp_reg,
               temp_cod 
           WHERE 
               temp_reg.cp = temp_code.cp";
$insert = $asies -> query($copiar);
```

All help is deeply appreciated.

SOLVED!!

Here is how got it to worked in case someone else needs a similar answer:

```
include("connect.php");
$query = mysqli_query($asies, "
INSERT INTO table3  (usr_id)
 SELECT table1.id FROM table1,table2
WHERE table1.cp = table2.cp")
 or die (mysqli_error($asies));
```

I specified the row for the INSERT INTO table and in the SELECT, I did as @Pete sugested.

Thank You All.

Comment: Are you sure conect isn't supposed to be connect?

Comment: I'm no expert in sub-queries, but I imagine you need brackets around the SELECT statement: `INSERT INTO temp_usr (SELECT * FROM temp_reg,temp_code WHERE temp_reg.cp = temp_code.cp)`. Also, yeah, there are a couple of typos too.

Comment: @AtkinsSJ - that's a special form of insert, doesn't require brackets.

Comment: Professional suggestion: Don't use `SELECT *` when doing `INSERT INTO ...SELECT`. Instead, be explicit about the columns in the `SELECT` list so that their order is deterministic:  `INSERT INTO temp_usr SELECT col1, col2, col3 FROM temp_reg...`

Comment: Agreed - the only time you can get away with `INSERT ... SELECT *` is when you're copying between duplicate tables.

Comment: @SamRamSan - Sometimes you don't get an answer that solves your problem, but when you do, click to accept the answer and you score points for it.

Comment: @Pete Thanks' man, I get it now, It was unconsidered of me, I'm fixing that right now.

Comment: If you solved your problem, consider posting an answer to this question, and accept it when you can. This will mark the question as closed.

Answer (score 0):

Oh My Cod - there's something fishy in your query.

```
INSERT INTO 
    temp_usr 
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    temp_reg,
    temp_code 
WHERE 
    temp_reg.cp = temp_code.cp
```

Your code is full of spelling mistakes. I've changed cod to code.

You'd do well to have some sort of error reporting too e.g.

```
or die(mysql_error())
```

Comment: Ok, I tried running this on MySQL

  INSERT INTO  `temp_usr` 
  SELECT * 
  FROM  `temp_reg` ,  `temp_cod` 
  WHERE  `temp_reg`.`cp` =  `temp_cod`.`cp`

And this is what PHP Myadmin says:
#1136 - Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
temp_usr and temp_reg have the same structure, temp_cod only holds two values ID column and the cp column

Comment: Well you're nearly there then - refer to Michael's comment above.

Comment: Thank you friends, here is how it worked:

    include("connect.php");
    $query = mysqli_query($asies, "INSERT INTO table3  (usr_id) SELECT table1.id FROM table1,table2 WHERE table1.cp = table2.cp") or    die (mysqli_error($asies));
    And ZZAAAP  it worked.

You guys been tremendous help.
Thank You.